# Access filtered data in ReactTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am using [ReactTable](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme), and have `filterable` set to `true`. I need to access the data that gets returned after applying filters, so I can generate CSV's of the filtered down data.

Any ideas on how I might be able to get the filtered down data, as JSON? Been messing around here https://react-table.js.org/#/story/custom-filtering, so far haven't found a way to grab the data that has been filtered down.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have just found the answer by referencing this [article](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/select-tree-table-hoc)

get refer of table like following:

```html
<ReactTable
  ref={(r) => {
    this.selectTable = r;
  }}
  ...
/>
```

And in your function

```
const currentRecords = this.selectTable.getResolvedState().sortedData;
```

Comment: I'm not using `<ReactTable ... >`, how can I get data from a `react-table` implemented like this https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/examples/basic

Answer (score 4):

If you are using React 16.7-alpha+ with hooks you can do something like the following too.

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';

const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(20);
let reactTable = useRef(null);

<ReactTable
    ref={(r) => (reactTable = r)}
    onFilteredChange={() => {
      setPageSize(reactTable.getResolvedState().sortedData.length);
    }}
/>
```

Comment: I'm not using `<ReactTable ... >`, how can I get data from a `react-table` implemented like this https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/examples/basic

Answer (score 1):

I'm using React 16.8 (which has full support for hooks, unlike the alpha answer). Not sure if the syntax changed, but this is what worked for me.

Also I'm using version 6.x of react-table. My enclosing component is a functional component.

```
const reactTable = React.useRef(null)

return <ReactTable ref={reactTable} .... />
```

I'm also using the checkboxHOC wrapper component like

```
const CheckboxTable = checkboxHOC(ReactTable)
return <CheckboxTable ref={reactTable} .... />
```

so to access the data, I have to chain some more calls (getWrappedInstance) like this

```
reactTable.current.getWrappedInstance().getResolvedState().sortedData
```

Example from the official documentation: https://github.com/TanStack/table/blob/v6.8.6/docs/src/examples/selecttable/index.js#L104-L111

Answer (score 0):

React table can take a render prop as a child, and you can pick data off the table state that is passed to that render fn,

```
<ReactTable {...props}>
    {(state, makeTable, instance) => {
        // take data from state, resolvedData, or sortedData, if order matters (for export and similar)
        // you need to call makeTable to render the table
        return (
                <>
                    {makeTable()}
                    {<p>{`Showing ${state.resolvedData.length} entries`}</p>}
                 </>
        );
      }}
</ReactTable>
```