# Can't access resolved data in react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I know this has been asked a few times on StackOverflow, but I haven't made any of the previous answers work for me. I'm looking to take a `react-table` component, and allow the user to download the filtered data currently rendered as a CSV. I know I'm going to need to use `react-csv` later on, but for now I'm struggling to even access the data in the table.

The issue I'm falling into is how to get the correct reference to the react-table component as it is a functional component. I always get the console warning:

> Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

This is using an implementation similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59288782/error-accessing-filtered-data-in-react-table). I've also tried the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120858/access-filtered-data-in-reacttable).

My code looks like the below:
I'm using conditional rendering for the table, the function which returns the table is:

```
showDataTable = () => {
// show data table if data is loaded only
    if (this.state.dataLoaded) {
        return(
            <DataTableV2
                data={this.state.data}
                columns={columns}
                ref={this.reactTable}
                />
        )
    }
}
```

`this.reactTable` at the moment is created from `reactTable = React.createRef();` in my class. I have also tried

```
<ReactTable
  ref={(r) => {
    this.selectTable = r;
  }}
  ...
/>
```

For now I just want to be able to console log the data just so I know I can access it, I'm doing so using `console.log(this.selectTable.getResolvedState().sortedData)`.

None of this is working - can someone please help out?