# how to get react-table filtered/sorted data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I want to get the filtered data of `react-table` I found some answers [Can't access resolved data in react-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65144515/cant-access-resolved-data-in-react-table), [Access filtered data in ReactTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120858/access-filtered-data-in-reacttable) and [Error accessing filtered data in React Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59288782/error-accessing-filtered-data-in-react-table).

but they all are using `<ReactTable ... >` or `<ReactTableComponent ...>` and with addressing the `ref` of the table they got data as `tableRef.getResolvedState().sortedData`.

my table looks like [this](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/examples/basic) and I have no `<ReactTable ...>`.

- `tableRef` returns the `<table class="table table-striped" role="table"> ....`
- `tableRef.current` return `undefined`
- `tabelRef.getResolvedState()` returns `undefined`

Comment: Those other questions all use an older version of the React-Table library. Ignore them, and maybe start by checking out [the useFilter docs for v7](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters). It'd also help a lot if you could provide more concrete details and a [Minimal Workable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [rows](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters#instance-properties) as **`rows.values`** to the values. as first `prepareRow(row)` each row then return the `values` of the row.

I assume you want to export filtered data as CVS.

```
import { CSVLink, CSVDownload } from "react-csv";
...

<CSVLink
  data={rows.map(row=> {
    prepareRow(row)
    return row.values;
  })}
>

  <button
    type="button"
    className="btn btn-round btn-outline-secondary mr-2"
  >
    <i className="ri-file-4-line" />
  </button>
</CSVLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I made is the following:

1. I added an argument to the React Table functional component where I will pass a callback function named *dataWasFiltered* `function Table({ columns, data, dataWasFiltered })`
2. I created a *useEffect* in my table component in order to use that callback anytime that *rows* property is updated `useEffect(() => { dataWasFiltered(rows) }, [rows])`
3. I created a state variable in parent object named *filtered* `const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(null)`
4. I created a callback function in parent objects that updates *filtered* state variable with *setFiltered* `const dataWasFiltered = x =>  setFilteredAssigned(x)`
5. In the parent component I added my new callback function as a parameter to the table component `<Table columns={columns} data={data} dataWasFiltered = { dataWasFiltered }/>`

What all this makes is to update in a state variable in parent component with the content of *rows* property of the react-table component. Rows property is the object that React-table renders, not all of the possible rows in the component.

Probably *dataWasFiltered* is not the most appropiate name for my callback but it is for which I will use it.

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using react-table 8.9.3:

```
const reactTable = useReactTable(...)
const rows = reactTable.getRowModel().flatRows
```