# How to get only filtered data in react table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm currently using React table and I need to filter data and then export it to csv. I can export data to csv but I get all data. I want to export only data that are shown after filtering table.

I'm using [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/). How to get only filtered data?

Comment: what do you mean by "filtered data" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120858/access-filtered-data-in-reacttable

Comment: @Nnay I got it working by passing rows instead of data property of React Table. I'm now passing rows.map(item => item.original). React Table have property rows in which you have all rows that are currently rendered on table instead of whole dataset that you passed to table. Each row has "original" property in which are stored data that are shown on that row.

Comment: could you explain a bit more how you got it working @FranTurkovic ? I am trying to do the same, but I cannot figure out!

Answer (score -2):

Now u can use "newAges" as new array of data and put it in your tables.

```js
const allData = [
  {
  age: 10,
    firstName: 'Charlie',
    lastName: 'White'
  },
  {
  age: 20,
    firstName: 'James',
    lastName: 'Bond'
  },
  {
  age: 35,
    firstName: 'Liz',
    lastName: 'Becket'
  },
{
  age: 5,
    firstName: 'Jhonas',
    lastName: 'Carlson'
  }
]

function checkAdult(x) {
  return x.age >= 18;
}


  const newAges = allData.filter(checkAdult);
   
console.log(newAges)
```

Comment: I want to get all filtered data. If I have table with columns: firstname, lastname and age, and I filter by age, I still want to get whole rows. I want to get all rows where people have specific age for example, so get firstname, lastname and age.

Comment: I got it working by passing rows in my CSV instead of data. I pass rows.map(item => item.original). You can access each row that is rendered in React Table and each row has attribute original in which are stored data that is shown. @Lygis